# Ruby - global "--no-document" with RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, documentation, rvm

**Without RVM:**

1. I've added `gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri` line to the `.gemrc` file in my home directory
2. When I run `sudo gem install gemX` the ruby gem is installed without the lines "parsing documentation for gemX" in the output

**Wiht RVM:**

1. The same line added to the same file
2. Lines "parsing documentation for gemX" are still being printed out in the terminal

**Question:**

How can I disable parsing the documentation when installing ruby gems while running ruby using RVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run below command on linux/unix/mac

```
echo 'gem: --no-document' >> ~/.gemrc
```

and then install any gem (even with rvm) and it should work